# How do I do a dry run with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know what docker-compose is going to do before I do it.

Is there a tool or flag which I can use to see what docker-compose would do without actually stopping containers and starting new ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dry run for `docker-compose` seems to be an [open feature request](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1203).

Comment: Thanks, I've added a comment and upvoted the OP.

Comment: This is still an open feature request sadly

Comment: Currently active PR: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/10173

Comment: [Now available under the 'alpha' command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_alpha_dry-run/): `docker compose alpha dry-run -- [CMD ...]` (As of compose v2.16.0, with more support / bug fixes in newer versions)